# how to add multiple pages in single html file

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a web app in which i have multiple pages i want that when i click on any link it should move to that page i got the code from site it works fine but i want that it does not show like the show Page1 Page but without onclick functions
without java script using ancchor tag

```
     <html>
     <head>
      <script>
     function show(shown, hidden) {
     document.getElementById(shown).style.display='block';
      document.getElementById(hidden).style.display='none';
     return false;
     }
    </script>
    </head>
   <body>


   <div id="Page1">
     Content of page 1
     <a href="#" onclick="return show('Page2','Page1');">Show page 2</a>
    </div>

    <div id="Page2" style="display:none">
    Content of page 2
     <a href="#" onclick="return show('Page1','Page2');">Show page 1</a>
    </div>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: I might be wrong (since I avoid html5 and other fancy new web technices, because I am old and grumpy) but did you declare your javascript right (is it ok to just say <script> in html5?. Could you try by changning your show function to a simple messagebox ?

Comment: Yes that's legal in HTML5 , but we can't see his doctype so who knows.

Comment: its is working fine but i want that instead of showbutton can i use any other thing

Comment: Like what an image? You can make it anything you want except 
    applet,
    base,
    basefont,
    bdo,
    br,
    font,
    frame,
    frameset,
    head,
    html,
    iframe,
    isindex,
    meta,
    param,
    script,
    style,
    title,

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution? Do you mind sharing it with us? ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS and checkboxes to get such a behaviour as written on this [SITE](http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/04/css-click-states/).

The checkbox is the only HTML element which has two different states which can be exported/evaluated by CSS via the `:checked` property.

Cited from http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/04/css-click-states/:
HTML:

```
<form class="clickable"> 
  <label for="the-checkbox">Click Me!</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="the-checkbox" /> 
  <!-- This is the div we want to appear and disappear -->
  <div class="appear">Some text to appear</div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.clickable .appear { 
  display: none;
}

.clickable input:checked ~ .appear {
  display: block;
}
```

Check out the demo at the bottom of that page.

To select among more than two pages, you could maybe use radio buttons. Not tested, just as an idea ;)